# Highcharts chart title doesn't print bold/strong attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have chart that in the title has elements that are wraped in `strong/bold` html elements. I have tried export to PDF, JPEG and PNG and all looks good. If I try to print then none of these are applied to text. I'm wondering if there is any fix for this? Also I have tried `useHTML`, that fixed some of the problems but if I try to export to PDF or other two formats text in my title is all the way to the left off the screen. I'm wondering how I can fix this issue to work on all formats and print page. Here is example:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/Lw8oo074/30/
```

I forgot to mention that I need bold/strong only around titles for each element not around JS variables. If anyone knows how this can be fixed please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: so, if `useHTML` already solved the *strong/bold* problem, try to explicitly apply `text-align: center` to your title in order to fix the consequences of `useHTML`

Comment: I have tried and text is still over the border to the left. I have checked with the dev tools and there is attribute `left:-178px`

Comment: what do you mean by *there is attribute* `left:-178px`?

Comment: @Scaramouche on `.highcharts-title` span element is css attribute left.

Comment: so `left:-178px` is an inline style applied to `.highcharts-title`? there you go, just remove it using JS and apply your own `left`

Comment: @Scaramouche I did and still that didn't apply on PDF, JPEG and print. I have tried to use css media to fix that but still is off over the border to the left...

Comment: please post the code you used to remove the inline built-in style and apply your own

Comment: @Scaramouche I have posted the link so you can test the code.

Comment: looks like you did not setup the fiddle properly, it throws *ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined*

Comment: @Scaramouche I just copy past the link and it works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169178/discussion-between-scaramouche-and-espresso-coffee).

Comment: I just checked it out and downloaded it in pdf format, everything looks perfect there, the lines ***Pure-Tone Audiogram***, ***Name:** John Cook **DOB:*** *01/23/2005* and ***Location:** New York* are all in the top-center area of the sheet. when loading the fiddle it does throw error *TypeError: n.forEach is not a function* but other than that, as I said, the pdf version at least looks in order. Side note: change *Frequencey* for *Frequency* :)

Comment: @Scaramouche I found on Highcharts forum discussion about this. Apparently if `useHtml` is set to `ture` that won't allow export. So only affects printing. I guess this is very limited feature in highcharts...

Comment: I printed the chart that you posted in your question. **Result:** https://ibb.co/mZmPU7 It seems to me that `<strong>` is applied but it's too delicate.

Comment: @KamilKulig I applied `<em>` around each value that is outputted in the title and `<strong>` around title name. That helped and works with printing and export. Thank you.